# Let $a,b\in G$. If $|a|$, $|b|$ finite then $|ab|$ finite for arbitrary group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Ah from my previous question, [If $|a|$, $|b|$ is finite then $|ab|$ is finite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2314282/if-a-b-is-finite-then-ab-is-finite?noredirect=1#comment4762491_2314282)
I made stupid assumption that $G$ is finite.

Assume arbitrary $G$. of finite order $a,b$ i mean,

Let $a,b\in G$, Assume the order of element $|a|$, $|b|$ is finite, then what i want to know is $|ab|$ finite?

Comment: @Bye_World, Here i assume $G$ is non-abelian, which means $(ab)^{mn} \neq a^{mn} b^{mn}$. $(ab)^{mn} = a(ba)^{mn-1} b$....

Comment: Yeah.  Brain fart.  I actually provided a counterexample in an answer, but then I saw carmichael beat me to it and deleted it.

Comment: [I already provided a counterexample in my answer to your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2314285/328173).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: consider the modular group $G=\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and the elements defined by the matrices
$$ S=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ 
and
$$ T=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

One can check that $S^2=(ST)^3=1$, but $T=S(ST)$ has infinite order.

Comment: Just noticed we had (essentially) the same answer -- and you beat me to it.  Darn! :-)

Comment: i am getting $S^4=I$

Comment: @Arun Badajena: notice it's $PSL_2$, so $I$ and $-I$ are identified.

Comment: oh oh!! got it.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that $|a|=|b|=2$ tells us nothing about $|ab|,$ because *every* permutation is the product of two involutions; this is Exercise 10.1.17 on p. 259 of [W. R. Scott's *Group Theory*](https://books.google.com/books?id=pOwxAwAAQBAJ).

For a concrete example, define two permutations $a,b$ of $\mathbb Z$ as follows:
$$a(n)=n-(-1)^n$$
$$b(n)=n+(-1)^n$$
Then $a(a(n))=b(b(n))=n,$ i.e., $|a|=|b|=2;$ but $|ab|=\infty,$ since $a(b(n))=n+2$ for even $n.$